# How to get media-id from Instagram URL

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

how can I get the media-id of a instagram posting from the url?

For example I need the media-id for https://www.instagram.com/p/Cf4dPucLzW0/

Solutions that does not work anymore:

- Oembed dont give media-id back
- adding ?__a=1 to a link redirects me to the post itself

Answer (score 4):

Put the following at the end of the post: `?__a=1&__d=dis`, e.g.:

`https://www.instagram.com/p/Cf4dPucLzW0/?__a=1&__d=dis`

Comment: Only works a couple of times. Then you get redirected.

Comment: @penguin_P did you find any solution?

Comment: @Mehmet Peker
Not really. If you use `?__a=1&__d=dis´ instead of `?__a=1` you well get blocked slower. If you have good rotating residential proxies, you can crawl some data. But this will work only for small amounts of crawls.

Comment: What is the true way to solve this issue?
Do you know it?

Comment: It is not possible to crawl instagram media

Answer (score 0):

you need to have pageid, access token and an short code (which can be extracted from the URL you have for eg if this is the url :https://www.instagram.com/reel/Cs12TgIv8Ns/. "Cs12TgIv8Ns" is the short code)

1. then you can use the page id to convert to instagram business id
   using the following url:
   url = Graph + endpoint + '?fields=' +
   instagram_business_account + '&access_token=' + Token
2. convert the short code to

```
    alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_'
    media_id = 0
    for letter in short_code:
        media_id = (media_id * 64) + alphabet.index(letter)
    IG_id_list.append(str(media_id))
```

3. then use the following url to get various metrics and media id
   [https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{instagram_business_account_id}/media?fields=....&access_token=token](https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/%7Binstagram_business_account_id%7D/media?fields=....&access_token=token)